# Ubuntu Server 18.04 Shutdown

Tags: 18.04, server, power-management, shutdown, acpi

Currently am running ubuntu server 18.04.

How can I modify the power button behaviour?

I want my system to get turned off when I hit the power button.

Edit: it's a headless unit so no GUI , Preferred method Terminal.

Comment: From the terminal or you want to configure it as a GUI user?

Comment: From terminal since i don't have Gooey it's a headless unit.

Comment: This question and answers (including the ACPI answers) should solve your problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50748/how-can-i-set-power-button-on-computer-case-to-power-off-system-with-systemd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the file /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh

Put these lines in the top:

```
/sbin/shutdown -h now "Power button pressed"
exit 0
```

Note that all connected users etc. will be force-closed.

Comment: I don't have such file under acpi shall I create one and write the string ?

Comment: Would be worth a try. Are you running the server version? In my VMWare installation I am running the desktop version and there I see this file.